# Eclipse RCP with drop down autosuggest on server response

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rap

Can I use apache solr in my existing Rich Client application?

I have been thinking to add/use Eclipse RAP in my existing RCP application and use an existing apache solr WAR( currently it is being used by other web client) for my product.
am I thinking in correct direction? 
Are there any alternatives?

Comment: what are you looking forward for implementation in rcp application? Jface has     org.eclipse.jface.fieldassist.AutoCompleteField

Comment: Thanks but my question is more related to server response data, like how can I use solr in RCP?

Comment: Unless and untill you restructure your question and tag proper labels, you are not putting attention to appropriate audience(helper).